# GZIPInputStream implementation for J2ME

Tags: java-me, gzip, gzipinputstream

Are there any GZIPInputStream implementation for J2ME available. I would prefer an Apache Style License

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC the [phoneME project](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/) includes an implementation of [GZIPInputStream](http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/14739_GZIPInputStream.java). I'm not sure of the licensing but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

[TinyLine implementation](http://tinyline.com/utils/index.html) should be OK also for commercial usages.

Comment: Well, Tinyline is good, however, the code is not open source, we just have an obfuscated jar file. What I would need is the source implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try: http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me Library is only 6.5k big.