# Compression in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, compression, gzip

Are there any OSS compression libraries (gzip) available for J2ME?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426154/gzipinputstream-implementation-for-j2me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/utils/index.html) GZip library. Download link [here](http://www.tinyline.com/utils/tinylinegzip/tinylinegzip.zip).

Comment: TinyLine GZip library is only to decompress

Answer (score 0):

software.informer.com/getfree-gzip-library-for-j2me/

swik.net/j2me+Library

try this link you can download free here

Answer (score 0):

Jazzlib-j2me (java.util.zip implementation in J2SE ported to J2ME) is available here: http://code.google.com/p/staff/downloads/list?q=jazzlib

gzip and gunzip is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The two compression algorithms which I have used for JavaME are :

i> GZip

ii>LZMA

GZip can be downloaded from the following link

- http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

Also , refer to the following link

- [Is there a GZIP J2ME library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095400/is-there-a-gzip-j2me-library)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in GZIP decompression library under http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me/. Uses only 7k (~5k after obfuscation). Compression is under development.