# Find common names in two files in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

First of all I want to make clear that the nature of this question is different than other questions which are already posted as per my knowledge. Please let me know if it is not so.

**Given**

1. I have a list of names ~3000.
2. There are ~2500 files which consists of names one at a line (taken from the name list)
3. Each file contains ~3000 names (and hence ~3000 lines, though avg is 400)

**Problem**

At a given time I will be provided with 2 files. I have to create a list of names which are common in both files.

**Pre Processing**

For reducing the time complexity I have done pre processing and sorted the names in all files.

**My Approach**

1. Sorted names in the given list and indexed them from 0 to 2999
2. In each file for each name

---

- Calculated the group number (name_index / 30)
- Calculated the group value (For each name in same group calculate (2^(name_index%30)) and add)
- Create a new file with same name in the format "groupNumber blankSpace groupValue"

---

**Result**

Instead of having ~3000(Though avg is 400) names in each file now I will have maximum 100 lines in each file. Now I will have to check for common group number and then by help of bit manipulation I can find out common names.

**Expectation**

Can anyone please suggest a shorter and better solution of the problem. I can do pre processing and store new files in my application so that minimum processing is required at the time of finding common names.

Please let me know if I am going in wrong direction to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Points**

In my approach the size of total files is 258KB (as I have used group names and group values) and if it is kept by names in each line it's size is 573KB. These files have to be stored on mobile device. So I need to decrease the size as far as possible. Also I am looking forward to data compression and I have no idea about how to do that. Please care to explain that also.

Comment: What are your performance requirements?

Comment: What's wrong with: 1. read a file line by line, add each line to a HashSet; 2. read a second file line by line, check whether the HashSet contains the given line or not. If yes, add it to results, if not, go on.

Comment: How many unique names do you have? If you like to end with 100 lines per file (by still 2500 files?) this would be 250 000 words=lines? What I don't understand too, is: `Each file contains ~3000 names, though avg is 400`. If each file contains 3000 names, avg would be 3000, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Slanec 
I considered doing with the logic you have given, and yes it's very straight forward. But the problem is the application is developed for mobile and hence the memory requirement should be very low. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @user_unknown

not each file contain 3000 line. But the upper limit is 3000 (which is the number of unique names). Many files have less names and hence the avg is 400. let me know if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following?

1. Read names 1 at a time from list1, adding them to a hashset.
2. Read names from list2 one at a time, looking them up in the hashset created from list one. If they are in the hashset, means the name is common to both files.

If you want to preprocess for some extra speed, store the # of names in each list and select the shorter list as list1.

Comment: My words exactly. I'm still confused, though. The question takes an ultrahard approach when the most simple and obvious answer is probably the fastest one, too. Is there anything we're missing? Like a no-memory-usage limitation?

Comment: possible things missing: performance requirements & op is java/programming novice unaware of what built in structures exist.

Comment: If the latter is the case, then this is for Comet: [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: @ Colin D

As the application is designed for mobile, I think memory requirement should be low.

Comment: I guess doing pre processing (As I have done in my approach) and then adding to hashset will solve the problem. As after pre processing the number of lines will be reduced to 100 at maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Given the **very low memory requirement** you stated in edit, there's another thing you could do.

Although I still think you could go for the solution other answers suggest. A `HashSet` with 3000 `String` entries won't get too big. My quick approximation with 16-char `Strings` suggests something below 400 kB of heap memory. Try it, then go back. It's like 25 lines of code for the whole program.

---

If the solution eats too much memory, then you could do this:

1. Sort the names in the files. That's always a good thing to have.
2. Open both files.
3. Read a line from both files.

   1. If `line1 < line2`, read a line from `line1`, repeat.
   2. If `line1 > line2`, read a line from `line2`, repeat.
   3. Else they are the same, add to results. Repeat.

It eats virtually no memory and it's a good place to use a `compareTo()` method (if you used it to sort the names, that is) and a `switch` statement, I think.

The size of the files doesn't influence the memory usage at all.

---

About the data compression - there are lots of tools and algorithms you could use, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085722/compression-in-j2me) (look at the related questions, too), or this [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20me%20compression).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems better solution. I had to reduce file size, so implemented mixed solution. Anyway thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to re-implement a Set with a List.   Don't do that.  Use a Set of names, which will automatically take care of duplications of inserts.

You need to read both files, there is no way around doing that.

```
// in pseudo-java
Set<String> names1 = new HashSet<String>();
for (String name : file1.getLine().trim()) {
  names1.put(name);
}

Set<String> names2 = new HashSet<String>();
for (String name : file2.getLine().trim()) {
  names2.put(name);
}

// with this line, names1 will discard any name not in names2
names1.retainAll(names2);

System.out.println(names1);
```

Assuming you use `HashSet` as this example does, you will be comparing hashes of the Strings, which will improve performance dramatically.

If you find the performance is not sufficient, *then* start looking for faster solutions.  Anything else *is* premature optimization, and if you don't know how fast it must run, then it is optimization without setting a goal.  Finding the "fastest" solution requires enumerating and exhausting every *possible* solution, as that solution you haven't checked yet *might* be faster.

Comment: You don't need to store the names from the second file since a simple `if (names1.contains(name))` check will do. But yeah.

Comment: @Slanec, yes but by calling `if (names1.contains(name))` multiple times (once for each name in file2) you create a few thousand JVM stack frames just for the purpose of destroying them, and force that computation of string hash right in the middle of your file read (which _might_ cause an IO stall under the "wrong" conditions).  On the other hand, my example _might_ use enough memory to force data out of cache.  When asking about faster, it is _always_ better to build something and then say "fast enough" or __can it be faster than this__.  Any statement made prior to measurement is risky.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood your requirements and situation.

You have about 2.500 files, each of 3000 words (or 400?). There are many duplicates of words which occur in multiple files.

Now somebody will ask you, which words have file-345 and file-765 in common.

You could create a Hashmap, where you store every word, and a List of Files, in which the words occur.

If you get File 345 with it's 3000 words (400?), you look it up in the hashmap, and see, where file 765 is mentioned in the list.

However 2 * 3000 isn't that much. If I create 2 lists of Strings in Scala (which runs on the JVM):

```
val g1 = (1 to 3000).map (x=> "" +  r.nextInt (10000))
val g2 = (1 to 3000).map (x=> "" +  r.nextInt (10000))
```

and build the intersection

```
g1.intersect (g2)
```

I get the result (678 elements) in nearly no time on an 8 years old laptop.

So how many requests will you have to answer? How often does the input of the files change? If rarely, then reading the 2 files might be the critical point.

How many unique words do you have? Maybe it is no problem at all to keep them all in memory.